Retry the transaction in case of rollback failures in Spring Hibernate
I have a function which calls stored procedures to update Oracle DB. I get this error log:
Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
I had used @Transactional annotation on this function to rollback calls. I want to retry the transaction upon Rollback failure while ensuring the calls  won't rewrite the changes once again upon retry.
I had considered using @Retryable(TransactionExcepion.class) on the functions. Does this work or is there any other better alternative for this question?
Thanks.

Post full stack trace.
